# I don't understand how javascript replace is working

Tags: javascript, replace

I have the following:

```
        xx = toString( '-' + toString( x ) + '-' );
        z = i.replace( /\-1\-/gi, '-3-' );
```

This does the replacement as stated, but if I do this:

```
        xx = toString( '-' + toString( x ) + '-' );
        z = i.replace( /\-1\-/gi, xx );
```

the replacement is "unknown object"
I need the later implementation to work since the replacement will vary.
How?

Comment: What do you expect `toString(`…`)` to do? String conversion is done with [`String(`…`)`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/String). `toString()` calls [`Object.prototype.toString`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) [without context](/a/3127440/4642212); the argument is ignored.

Comment: Make sure to provide the sample strings and the desired output string! What are `xx` and `x` ? `z` should look like...? Please, [edit], create a [mcve].

Comment: Why do you assume this has anything to do with `replace`? Have you looked at what `toString( '-' + toString( x ) + '-' )` is? Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`).

Answer (score 0):

You have implement the .toString() function in a wrong way. Check this out for more details [Object.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString?retiredLocale=vi) and [Array.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString?retiredLocale=vi)

A quick fix for your code:

```html
let xx = `-${x.toString()}-`
let z = i.replace( /\-1\-/gi, xx );
```

Comment: `.toString()` is redundant in the template literal.

Comment: true, i add it in just for illustation purpose